# Disposing of SWT Event Listeners

Tags: java, swt, listener, dispose, lifecycle

I am working on a SWT Desktop application where we use a lot of listeners for our various widgets. Currently I'm trying to manage the lifecycle of these listeners and while I have come to a solution, I was curious if I missed something or if I could have done things better.

The situation is as follows:

When performing data binding, according to attribute information, several SWTEventListener(s) are created (Verify, Modify, Focus...). By default, they are simply added to the widget's event table, but because removing a listener requires a specific instance, aka:

```
widget.removeListener(SWT.Verify, formatVerifyListener);
```

We decided to save all listeners in a multi map (`Map<Widget, List<AbstractDataBindingListener>`) and when we dispose this particular context, we try and remove said listeners:

```
for(Entry<Widget, List<AbstractDataBindingListener>> entry : boundWidgets.entrySet()) {
    for (AbstractDataBindingListener listener : entry.getValue()) {
        entry.getKey().removeListener(listener.getSwtEvent, listener);
    }
    entry.getValue().clear();
}
boundWidgets.clear(); // rendundant?
boundWidgets = new HashMap<>();
```

This did not work. The abstract class was declared as a Listener so that `widget.removeListener(...)` would accept it, and it did, but all these SWTEventListeners were Typed listeners, aka they did contain the exact listener inside them but they would fail the if within EventTable.unhook

```
public void unhook (int eventType, Listener listener) {
    if (types == null) return;
    for (int i=0; i<types.length; i++) {
        if (types [i] == eventType && listeners [i] == listener) {
            remove (i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Because:

```
listeners [i] == listener
// listeners [i] -> the listener I want removed
// listener -> typed listener, different from listener [i]
// but it wraps the correct listener
```

Thus the if fails, the listener is not removed.

However Widget does have a method that would work, aka

```
protected void removeListener (int eventType, SWTEventListener listener) {
    checkWidget();
    if (listener == null) error (SWT.ERROR_NULL_ARGUMENT);
    if (eventTable == null) return;
    eventTable.unhook (eventType, listener);
}

// EventTable unhook
public void unhook (int eventType, SWTEventListener listener) {
    if (types == null) return;
    for (int i=0; i<types.length; i++) {
        if (types [i] == eventType) {
            if (listeners [i] instanceof TypedListener) {
                TypedListener typedListener = (TypedListener) listeners [i];
                if (typedListener.getEventListener () == listener) {
                    remove (i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, I can't access it. The only way to access it is with `.removeVerifyListener`, `.removeFocusListener`, `.removeModifyListener`

The final solution was to create an abstract dispose method and force each and every listener to have a copy of the widget they are attached to (hoping no one attaches them to other widgets and don't update things correctly) so that they can remove themselves:

```
public class FloatFormatterVerifyListener extends AbstractDataBindingListener implements VerifyListener {

    // ...

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        for (Widget widget : boundWidgets)
            if (widget != null && !widget.isDisposed()) {
                widget.removeVerifyListener(this);
            }
    }
}
```

While this works, and IMHO is sorta elegant ... it is not foolproof. One could still use widget.addVeifyListener(floatFormatterVerifyListener) to another widget and dispose will not work for that widget. Whoever added it should also save the instance of the listener and dispose of it manually.

But most situations are similar to the above one, we have many listeners of disparate types in a list, each requiring their own `.remove[Type]Listener`.

---

So what are the solutions? Should we always hide the actual listener (implements VerifyListener) as a private interior class, and manage how they are added by the parent class who would be responsible of keeping track of widgets and being able to properly dispose itself, or is there another way that doesn't require reflection or instanceof?

Comment: It generally isn't necessary to remove listeners. The automatic control dispose does that.

Comment: @greg-449 Our use case requires it. We've had text fields with 40+ listeners, we've had text fields that should be unbound still acting like they were bound, despite not writing data in the model.

Comment: Do you have to use the typed listeners (`VerifyListener` etc) or could you just use the lower level `Listener`. Typed listeners always just translate to one or more Listeners.

Comment: @greg-449  I doubt the swt listeners do anything extra when it comes to the event and how it is handled. But I'm working with a couple of dozens of listeners here, more maybe. I don't want to re-invent the wheel, just to properly handle their life cycle. The reason for this complication is the business logic, the instance of bound attributes changes every UI update (more or less. Big actions changes the whole model object), thus databinding (among other things) has to be completely disposed and rebuilt.